# What are the differences between MKNetworkKit and AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, macos, networking, afnetworking, mknetworkkit

I'm running some test on those two networking framework: MKNetworkKit and AFNetworking. And I am seeing that it is not easy to see the differences between the two libs. What are the major differences between the two?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`MKNetworkKit`:

- Cache on disk included.
- Frozen operations (offline requests can be queued to be executed when the network is back).
- More lightweight.

`AFNetworking`:

- More users and contributors.
- Better documentation (clearer and more accessible).
- `UIImageView+AFNetworking` for lazy image loading (possible in MKNK, but more painful).
- Standard (Apple-like) coding style.
- Better leverage of SDK objects (NSCoding compliant).
- Great variety of extra features and extensions (e.g. network reachability, streaming multipart form requests, backgrounding support, etc).
- Has a nice project logo. ;-)

Anything else?

Comment: AFNetworking allows caching with the NSURLRequest Class. For my personal opinion MKNetworkKit has a really strange OOP structur and AFNetworking is the better solution for the long time support (MKNetworkKit is a one man show, AFNetworking is from Gowalla).

Comment: AFNetworking has many more features to name (network reachability, streaming multipart form requests, backgrounding support, an ecosystem of dozens of extensions, etc.), but I want to point out that AFN also has cache on disk and operation freezing (pause / resume as well as `NSCoding` compliance), FWIW.

Comment: Also, FWIW, the code for MKNetworkKit looks more careless and rushed. The coding style is non-standard (whitespace use), and one of the main classes has only half the code broken into #pragma sections, the other half just having everything splurged into one at the top of the file.

Comment: Also, swear words in the comments never creates a good impression. I'm looking at you, MKNetworkKit.

Comment: AFNetworking code is generally just more rounded. For example, some of the main classes implement NSCoding. And there are helper methods for calling DELETE, POST etc. provided.

Comment: I don't know that swear words in comments necessarily bother me. But commenting about such a thing, without providing anything to back it up does!